# Using MonoDroid is there a way to do a DoClick() switch / case statement with buttons?

Tags: android, button, xamarin.android, switch-statement

I'm just trying to port some code I wrote in native Android / Java to MonoDroid - but I get the following error when I click a button:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method DoClick(View) in the activity class icantalk.android.CreateProfile for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'createProfilePicBtn'

```
    public void DoClick(View view)
    {
        switch (view.Id)
        {
            case Resource.Id.createProfilePicBtn:
                {
                    Log.Error("Profile Pic", "Clicked");
                    break;
                }
            case Resource.Id.createProfileSbmtBtn:
                {
                    Log.Error("Save Button", "Clicked");
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

The relevant parts of my layout xml are:

```xml
      <Button
      android:id="@+id/createProfilePicBtn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
      android:onClick="DoClick"
      android:text="@string/createProfileImgBtnTxt" />

      <Button
      android:id="@+id/createProfileSbmtBtn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
      android:onClick="DoClick"
      android:text="@string/createProfileSaveBtnTxt" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registering events in this way is currently not supported for MonoDroid.

You can register the event using code:

```
public override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    //Do other oncreate stuff here (including SetContentView etc)

    //Register the event for your first button
    Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.id.createProfilePicBtn);
    btn.Click += DoClick;

    //Register the event for your second button
    Button btn2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.id.createProfileSbmtBtn);
    btn2.Click += DoClick;
}


public void DoClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    View view = (View)sender;
    switch (view.Id)
    {
       case Resource.Id.createProfilePicBtn:
       {
          Log.Error("Profile Pic", "Clicked");
          break;
       }
       case Resource.Id.createProfileSbmtBtn:
       {
           Log.Error("Save Button", "Clicked");
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting with Mono for Android 4.2, you can now export the "DoClick" method to allow this to be called from the Axml (see http://docs.xamarin.com/android/Releases/Mono_For_Android_4/Mono_For_Android_4.2#Exporting_arbitrary_Java_member_for_better_Java_integration for more information)